# Help with MySQLTuner and MySQL Configuration

Tags: mariadb, mysqltuner

I am running my server on Cloudways AWS server; it's a LearnDash WordPress website.
I tried to adjust the server config as their support does not want to do anything with that.

I have a 16 vCPU and 32 GB RAM

I usually have like 3GB of RAM used and 13% of CPU but suddenly the usage just goes extremely high and the server goes down due to MySQL and queries (what Cloudways support said)

I was wondering if you can help me understand MySQLTuner and maybe give me some pointers in what I can do with it?

This is the MySQLTuner output.
If you can point me in the right direction for php.ini config as well it will be much appreciated

```
[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[!!] Failed to execute: SHOW REPLICA STATUS\G                                                                                                                                                                                            
[!!] FAIL Execute SQL / return code: 256                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[!!] Failed to execute: SHOW SLAVE STATUS                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[!!] FAIL Execute SQL / return code: 256                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.6.3-MariaDB-1:10.6.3+maria~buster-log                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
[!!] Log file  doesn't exist                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 10.6G (Tables: 105)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
[--] Up for: 1d 19h 29m 16s (39M q [253.332 qps], 279K conn, TX: 839G, RX: 6G)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[--] Reads / Writes: 97% / 3%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[--] Binary logging is disabled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[--] Physical Memory     : 30.4G                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 153.2G                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[--] Other process memory: 0B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[--] Total buffers: 2.8G global + 1.0G per thread (150 max threads)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[--] Performance_schema Max memory usage: 0B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 41.9G (137.73% of installed RAM)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 153.2G (503.69% of installed RAM)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (349/39M)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 26% (39/150)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.34% (936/279187)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[!!] Name resolution is active: a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection which can reduce performance                                                                                                                                                                    
[!!] Query cache may be disabled by default due to mutex contention.                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 10.6% (4M cached / 41M selects)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[!!] Query cache prunes per day: 35147                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 10% (174K temp sorts / 1M sorts)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 18728                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 67% (513K on disk / 756K total)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[--] Thread cache not used with thread pool enabled                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 99% (7M hits / 7M requests)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[OK] table_definition_cache (400) is greater than number of tables (184)                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (60/32K)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (75 immediate / 75 locks)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
[!!] Performance_schema should be activated.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
[--] Sys schema is not installed.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[--] Thread Pool Size: 128 thread(s).                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.6.3-MariaDB-1:10.6.3+maria~buster-log)                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
[--] InnoDB is enabled.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[!!] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.5G / 10.6G                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[!!] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size (5%): 128.0M * 1 / 2.5G should be equal to 25%                                                                                                                                                                                  
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 20 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances                                                                                                                                                                                    
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.88% (10547518318 hits / 10559895724 total)                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 158.73% (440849 hits / 277733 total)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 718582 writes)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                      
General recommendations:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    Run ALTER TABLE ... FORCE or OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance                                                                                                                                                                                               
      ALTER TABLE `xxmjcawbqz`.`wp_woocommerce_sessions` FORCE; -- can free 92 MiB                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Total freed space after defragmentation: 92 MiB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    7 CVE(s) found for your MySQL release. Consider upgrading your version !                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1                                                                                                                                                                              
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.                                                                                                                                                                                               
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html                                                                                                                                                                                                             
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/FromDual/mariadb-sys for MariaDB
    Before changing innodb_log_file_size and/or innodb_log_files_in_group read this: https://bit.ly/2TcGgtU                                                                                                                                                                               
Variables to adjust:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    skip-name-resolve=1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    query_cache_size (=0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    query_cache_type (=0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    query_cache_limit (> 2M, or use smaller result sets)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    query_cache_size (> 64M)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    join_buffer_size (> 256.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    tmp_table_size (> 16M)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    max_heap_table_size (> 16M)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    performance_schema=ON                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 10.6G) if possible.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    innodb_log_file_size should be (=640M) if possible, so InnoDB total log file size equals 25% of buffer pool size.
```

These are my buffer values:

```
key_buffer_size |64.000 MB |
query_cache_size |64.000 MB |
innodb_buffer_pool_size |2560.000 MB |                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size |0.000 MB |
innodb_log_buffer_size |16.000 MB |                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
sort_buffer_size |2.000 MB |
read_buffer_size |0.125 MB |
read_rnd_buffer_size |0.250 MB |
join_buffer_size |0.250 MB |
thread_stack |0.285 MB
binlog_cache_size |0.031 MB |
tmp_table_size |16.000 MB |
```

MEMORY PER CONNECTION |18.941 MB

Unfortunately I do not have access to the my.cnf file but I can change some values if needed.

Comment: You have clearly overallocated memory to MySQL: `Maximum reached memory usage: 41.9G (137.73% of installed RAM)`, however, if you " do not have access to my.cnf file" it's not clear how you're planning to fix your configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to determine MySQL pre-allocated memory footprint?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30991/is-it-possible-to-determine-mysql-pre-allocated-memory-footprint)

Comment: 10.6.3 is really should be [updated](https://mariadb.org/download/?t=repo-config&d=Debian+10+"buster"&v=10.6). Many fixes have [occured](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-106-series/)

Answer (score 0):

> CPU but suddenly the usage just goes extremely high and the server goes down

That sounds like the "thundering herd" problem.  *Decrease*  `max_connections` so that the sudden onrush of connections does not overwhelm the server.

Also, use the [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) to find out which queries are the 'worst' and let's discuss how to improve them.

Meanwhile, MySQLTuner has some good points and some dubious points.

If you are not swapping, then it is not really exceeding the RAM.

The "Query cache" has been removed from future versions -- too little benefit, too many drawbacks.

Unless you do have lots of other RAM users, increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of *available* ram.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i have another one regarding max_connections if you don't mind.... 'Max_used_connections' is that an indication of how max_connections should be set? and can i calculate this value somehow?

Comment: @techteam - `VARIABLES` can be set; `STATUS` are metrics that indicate what is going on.  `Max_used_connections` is a "high-water-mark" saying how much of `max_connections` was actually used since the restart of RWS.  If they are equal, then users may have been denied connections.  If 'used' is relatively low, you _could_ lower `max_connections` to keep a lid on memory usage.   39/150 in 2 days -- It sounds OK.  That ratio is 'typical'.

Comment: does Max_used_connections reset after a certain amount of time? can i check it daily to make sure i didn't go above the '150' mark? or does it display the maximum number of connections from the start of the mysql service? and as long as it doesn't  go beyond the '150' mark i am okay?

Comment: Yes.  `Max_used_connections` resets when the server (mysqld) restarts.  It won't exceed 151 (150 regular logins, plus 1 emergency login); instead, users will be denied connections.  Half the max might be worth noting.  If a hacker is attacking you, this limit is some line of defense.  So, it is unclear what is "okay".